# Using static fragments with CoordinatorLayout of the new Design Support Library

Tags: android, android-support-library, android-toolbar, android-coordinatorlayout

I've been experimenting with the new offerings of the library and I just can't wrap my head around customizing it the way I want.

I am taking as a reference this sample code: https://github.com/chrisbanes/cheesesquare

I have successfully managed to add a static [fragment](https://gist.github.com/appoll/334c59398dec4703289e) (contains some FrameLayout with recyclerView and additional empty views) as the child of the CoordinatorLayout, which works as expected when scrolling the (ugly) recycler view inside it.

The working [gist](https://gist.github.com/appoll/d863a09f25076061e881) and the result:

[image: Recycler view with elements]

I am only trying to add one extra CardView above my fragment, which should also have the same effect on the toolbar when dragged upwards. I tried adding them both to a LinearLayout inside a NestedScrollView, together with other various combinations, of which none was successful. Whenever I tap on the cardview, they are displaced and never again in their own place. Moreover, dragging the cardview still fades out the toolbar, but nothing else happens.

The non-working [gist](https://gist.github.com/appoll/0104ddc8a13e6de49b45) and the result:

[image: Empty recycler view]

Answer (score 0):

I came across a different issue using `CoordinatorLayout` as the container for my fragments: https://code.google.com/p/android/issues/detail?id=179600

It seems `CoordinatorLayout` has a number of issues with this use case. The solution is likely to use a `FrameLayout` instead to contain your fragment, then put the `CoordinatorLayout` as the top level container of your fragment's UI.